# How do I get specific values from a datasnapshot in flutter using cloud firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Data from the snapshot isn't storing in the variables (_gender, _email, verify).

```
    Firestore.instance.collection('Matrimonial').where('email', isEqualTo: _userEmail)
      .snapshots().listen(
            (data) {
              setState(() {
                this._gender = data.documents[0]['gender'];
                this._verify = data.documents[0]['verify'];
              });
            } 
      );
```

Maybe the query isn't correct, please help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot to add ".data" after the array of snapshots, try this.

```dart
Firestore.instance.collection('Matrimonial').where('email', isEqualTo: _userEmail)
      .snapshots().listen(
            (data) {
              setState(() {
                this._gender = data.documents[0].data['gender'];
                this._verify = data.documents[0].data['verify'];
              });
            } 
      );
```